# Microsoft FTP Service 451 The parameter is incorrect

Tags: qt, ftp

I'm trying to write a ftp client.
I have two ftp servers. The first server is a standard FTP server from Microsoft. The second server was written in the organization where I work.
My program with the second server works well.
But my program is the first server receives the error: "451 The parameter is incorrect".
What can be wrong?
I use Qt 4.8.4, Windows 7.

```
...
switch(cod) {
    case 220:   
       user=sett.value("userFTP",QString("anonymous")).toString();
       logMessage(codec1->toUnicode("Авторизация пользователя ")+user);
       buf = QByteArray::fromRawData("USER ",5) + "\n";
       sock->write(buf);
       logMessage(buf);
       break;
...
```

Comment: First ftp server (microsoft) works correctly if I use a command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bug. I used ASCII. but I had to use the Latin 1.